# Synchronous motor: intuitive explanation of f = 120/PN

Tags: motor, frequency, speed, synchronous-motor

In **synchronous motors**, let f be the frequence, P the number of poles and N the number of tours per second:

$$f =  \frac{120}{PN}$$

I don't understand this relation at all. In my opinion, the more poles you have, the less reluctance you have in the magnetic circuit (less air between the magnets), so the highest the speed should be. Yet:

$$P \propto \frac{1}{N} \tag{1}$$

Moreover, the highest the frequency of the electrical circuits is, the highest should be the speed  since for f = 0, you have a DC current which does not product any rotating magnetic field. Yet:

$$f \propto \frac{1}{N} \tag 2$$

Could someone give me an intutive way to understand relations (1) and (2) please ?

---

**Update**: as pointed out in the comments, it is *pairs* of poles and number of tours per *minute*, sorry for the confusion

Comment: (2) is the very definition of frequency. Are you positive (1) is about tours/turns *per second*, not *per minute*? (With electrical machines, I'm more used to *pole pairs*, which removes a factor of 2…)

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is per minutes and pole pairs.

Comment: So N is the time to make a tour, not the number of tours per minute thus ? If this is the definition of frequency f = 1/T

Comment: So, first, how would you define "frequency"?"

Comment: the number of tours per second ?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, it was just a big blunder from me. The true equation is:

$$f = \frac{PN}{120}$$

which is totally logical and answers my problems. Sorry for the time wasted.